# performance difference between creating a closure and some_func.bind(this)

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, prototypejs

I'm writing a lot of code in javascript lately and I'm using Prototype.js to help with a lot of the boilerplate, just the bind method is more than worth it since I like using closures instead of objects to do the heavy lifting. It's hard to give up habits picked up from using ruby blocks. So here's my question: Is there any particular performance difference between

```
var func = some_func.bind(this);
...
func();
```

and

```
var that = this;
...
some_func(); // we just rename 'this' everywhere inside some_func to 'that'
```

These tricks are required because inner functions default to the global context instead of the context of the outer function. In particular which version keeps things more 'flat'. If there is recursion involved then the bind version will come to a crawl because bind will keep folding functions inside functions until unrolling things is impossible, at least I think that's what happens. Does the second version have the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The performance difference is really extremely negligible unless you are running the operation thousands of times in rapid fire. So I'd usually go with the bind because it makes for cleaner, less bug-prone code.

Comment: Regarding the actual performance difference, I really don't know, but I *do* know that chances are 99.99% that you don't need to concern yourself with that difference.

Comment: Actually I ran into a problem with a recursive function call that had a bind call and it obviously came to a crawl and I started to wonder if creating a closure with 'var that = this;' keeps things more 'flat'.

Comment: As I said, I really don't know what the performance difference is, but I do know that both methods should be very fast. Are you sure there isn't another bug at play here? How many iterations of recursion did it go through? All I can say without more details is that I've never personally had a problem with recursive functions and bind().

Comment: I'm certain there is no bug involved other than calling bind a whole bunch and short of hand tracing the program I'm not sure how to track all the folding that bind performs.

Comment: yeah, i guess you should better wait for someone more qualified than me to answer this. usually when people have questions like this, they are pre-optimizing for something that isn't actually a performance problem, which is the assumption i was under, but in this case that was a wrong assumption -- seems like in your case you actually have a problem to solve =).

Comment: I completely agree with Ben here.  Plus, it has been added as a language feature in Javascript 1.8.5, so browsers supporting this should be pretty quick if your version of bind hasn't overwritten the browser's native version.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind